# Running migrations prepends schema public to CREATE statements in structure.sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

When running `$ rails db:migrate`, regardless if any migrations have been added or not, structure.sql changes removing `SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;` and replacing it with `SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);` then prepending `public.` to every `CREATE` statement.

Example:

`CREATE FUNCTION round_minutes(timestamp without time zone, integer) RETURNS timestamp without time zone`

Becomes:

`CREATE FUNCTION public.round_minutes(timestamp without time zone, integer) RETURNS timestamp without time zone`

Using:

- PostgresSQL v10.4
- Rails 5.2.0

The issue appears to affect those of us using Postgres version above 9.6.5

Is there a way to configure Postgres not to do this?

Answer (score 4):

There was a [vulnerability in Postgresql](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2018-1058) that was fixed in March, 2018.

If you are using Postgresql version 10.3, 9.6.8, 9.5.12, 9.4.17, 9.3.22, or higher point version then it will specify the public schema in table references and set the pg_catalog search_path.

Perhaps someone on your team is using an older version of Postgresql causing the structure.sql to revert.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent this to happen without updating the Postgresql version?

Comment: @NatassiaTavares I can only suggest having everyone update Postgresql or refrain from committing the changes to version control.